# Print SELECT list from databse using Mysqli array function

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to print a select list on my webpage using Mysqli select query. I have checked a lot of questions there, but i am failed to find my problem. Pls help.

**php**

```
<select name="bcat" id="bcat" required="required" class="search-field">
<option value="" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select a Category</option>
<?php getTierOne(); ?>
</select>
```

**getTierOne()**

```
function getTierOne()
{
   $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT bcat FROM advertise");

   while($tier = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))   
   {
     echo '<option value="' .$tier['bcat'] . '">' . $tier['bcat'] . '</option>';
   }
}
```

**db.php**

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'lwv');

if($mysqli->connect_errno > 0){
die('Unable to connect to database [' . $mysqli->connect_error . ']');
}
```

It is working absolutely fine with sql query and syntax but not working with mysqli query. I don't have knowledge about mysqli queries so please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the `error_log` say?

Comment: what is the error?let us know the exact error.You can view it from error_log also set error_reporting on

Answer (score 1):

you have to pass `$mysqli` to the finction

try this

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'lwv');


if($mysqli->connect_errno > 0){
die('Unable to connect to database [' . $mysqli->connect_error . ']');
}
?>
<select name="bcat" id="bcat" required="required" class="search-field">
<option value="" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select a Category</option>
<?php getTierOne($mysqli); ?>
</select>


<?php
function getTierOne($mysqli)
{
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT bcat FROM advertise");

  while($tier = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 

    {
       echo '<option value="' .$tier['bcat'] . '">' . $tier['bcat'] . '</option>';
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much...it is working absolutely for me....

Comment: you are welcome,  please mark the answer as accepted

Comment: this answer worked for me...i would like to mark it as correct...

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting variable `$mysqli` inside the function.

Make this variable `global`.

Change

```
function getTierOne() {
```

to

```
function getTierOne() {
 global $mysqli;
```

Or, else pass database connection as parameter:

```
function getTierOne($mysqli = NULL) {
```